# JavaScript IF Statement to change Link classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JS that currently gets the URL of a website, splits the URL to a particular string and stores it in a variable

I then have an IF statement that depending on that string will add a class to my links. However, the i can't get the IF statement to work. It seems to do the action even if the condition has been met.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/Carrot654321/pen/YazXBv - Code here

```
   const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a")
   var url = window.location.href;

    url = url.split("/");



    if (url[2] = "s.codepen.io") {
     navLinks[1].classList.add("active");

     } 
    else {
    navLinks[3].classList.add("active"); 

     }
```

Comment: = is for assignment, == is for comparison. Replace = with == in your if condition and see what happens

Comment: To the people downvoting, this is a genuine question and an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a")
   var url = window.location.href;

    url = url.split("/");



    if (url[2] === "s.codepen.io") {
     navLinks[1].classList.add("active");

     } 
    else {
    navLinks[3].classList.add("active"); 

     }
```

use `===` instead of `=` and don't use `==` as you will experience weird behavior because `==` does type conversion before comparison.

have a look at this -  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons](http://===%20vs%20==)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, quite new to this so still making some silly mistakes

Comment: happy coding @Nick

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you have a single equals instead of a triple equals.

```
    if (url[2] = "s.codepen.io")
```

This is assigning a value instead of comparing on it so it always returns true.

It should be:

```
    if (url[2] === "s.codepen.io")
```